# Trying to save data coming a segue in swift on the home

Tags: ios, swift, save, segue

Setup - I have a viewcontroller passing data to another viewcontroller using a protocol and segue. The seque is working fine and the string is being passed back to the (home) screen. 
The data fields are empty at first, then populated later from the other view controller.

Issue - I can't seem to save the data on the home view controller when I close the app and come back in. On other viewcontrollers I am using UserDefaults and it is working (no segues).

Expected Behaviour: display the saved data when opening the app (a second time)

Question - Is it possible to save and display the data coming from a segue on the home?

FYI - I am new to swift programming.

Comment: Could you show up some code what you have done so far and what is not working

Comment: Check if value exists against the specific key in UserDefaults in Home ViewController in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: If the data display in VCA when you return, you could save in VCA (home) once you have returned. Or, as explained, could do it in the prepare for segue in VCB, saving to userDefaults or to any persistent storage you select.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question but will try to answer it as well as I understand it from your question :

So, you have a ViewControllerA which performs a segue to show ViewControllerB and in ViewControllerA's overridden `prepareForSegue` method, you set the delegate of ViewControllerB.

Now, you save some data to UserDefaults in ViewControllerB and on restarting the app, you want ViewControllerA to load the data from UserDefaults.

My suggestion is to check if the data exists in UserDefaults in the `viewWillAppear` method of ViewControllerA (and if so load it and set the text for the UI labels, and textFields at this point). If ViewControllerB needs this data too, you can pass it to ViewControllerB in ViewControllerA's overridden `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did the check, and the data does exist. Where do I "load it and set the text"? In the viewWillAppear func? What does that code look like? Sorry again - I am just learning how to code in Swift.

Comment: You will need to create an IBOutlet to your UILabel and then in your viewWillAppear method set the text using `label.text = "Hello, world" ` . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043323/changing-text-of-swift-uilabel for example code.